# How can i draw polygons on an HTML5 canvas through a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

i want the user to be able to click somewhere on the canvas and the polygon will appear on it

```
<DIV id="canvasarea" class="rounded">
    <CANVAS id="canvas" width="800px" height="800px"></CANVAS>
    </DIV>
```

Comment: Please note that it should be width="800" height="800", i.e., without the "px". The value of these attributes defines the abstract coordinate system, not the size of the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Use a javascript library, I'd try processingjs first - keep in mind IE has to be tricked into supporting canvas.

I didn't see a sample that matched your request exactly but these two should give you a good starting point

http://processingjs.org/learning/basic/shapeprimitives

same-domain-as-above/learning/topic/continuouslines

there is also a great primer on canvas here - google "dive into html5 canvas"

Comment: I agree. Also using a JavaScript library will give you better browser support. My favorite is RaphaelJS: http://raphaeljs.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I included in an object using mootools library. You could implement it in plain javascript too. ctx is equal to canvas.getContext('2d') object and n var defines the number of sides for the polygon we want... I hope you get the idea, the solution is requires only basic math.

```
 polygonPath: function(ctx, n) {
        var eq = 360 / n;
    var radius = 50;

    this.points = {xy: []};
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(50,0);

    for (var i = 0 ; i <= n; i++){
        var deg = i * eq;
        var rad = this.radConst * deg;
        var x1 = radius * Math.cos(rad);
        var y1 = radius * Math.sin(rad);
        console.log('x: ' + x1 + ', y: ' + y1 + ', deg: ' + deg);
        ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);

        this.points.xy.push(x1 + ',' + y1 + ',' + rad);
    }   

    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

            /* Pentagon:
        point 1 : 50,0
        point 2: 15.45, 47.55
        point 3: -40.45, 29.38
            point 4: -40.45, -29.38
        point 5: 15.45, -47.55
        point 6 : 50, -1.22e-14*/                       
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

KineticJS is a great way to get started quickly.  Here's an example that shows you how to draw a polygon on the canvas:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-polygon-tutorial/

Detect your click and then run the logic provided in the example.

Answer (score 0):

From here: http://www.authorcode.com/draw-and-fill-a-polygon-and-triangle-in-html5/

You can use the lineTo() method:

```
var objctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

objctx.beginPath();
objctx.moveTo(75, 50);
objctx.lineTo(175, 50);
objctx.lineTo(200, 75);
objctx.lineTo(175, 100);
objctx.lineTo(75, 100);
objctx.lineTo(50, 75);
objctx.closePath();
objctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
objctx.fill();
```

If you not want to fill the polygon use the `stroke()` method in the place of `fill()`

Thanks.