# Modifying image in a C# WPF apllication

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to modify specific parts of an image when clicking on them in a C# application. I'll describe the situation in detail:

**Task**

I want to add a graphical element to an existing C# application. The graphic I want to use is a shell, similar to: https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/658/484/non_2x/snail-shell-on-white-vector.jpg

Each segment of the shell **has to react to click events**. Given the nature of the graphic, each segment has a unique form and size. There is a total of 189 segments.
Clicking on a segment must call some methods in code behind. Depending on code behind values, segments must be **colored in 3 stages (empty, half, full)**.

**Environment**

Existing Application is a C# WPF app using .NET framwork 4.5

The graphic only exists on paper, so can only be scanned and used in the app as an image file (of any format)

**What I've tried**

I loaded the graphic in a WebBrowser element, using it as image in an HTML file. Segments are defined by HTML areas, calls to code behind methods and vice versa via JavaScript.

**Where I am:**

Almost everything worked. Defining areas is relatively little work. Calling code behind via JavaScript worked surprisingly well. **However, I couldn't change the graphic from code behind.** HTML areas cannot take CSS properties, so they can't be colored this way. Adding overlays to the DOM onclick would work but would also mean creating 378 additional images (189 segments * 2 states). I'd prefer not to...

**What I need:**

Some hint how I can manage this. Is there any way to make what I already have work? Or am I totally on the wrong path and there is some entirely different approach I'm not seeing? I'm willing to scrap what I've done so far if I must. Using external libraries/3rd party tools would be OK as long as they're free.

I considered rebuilding the graphic using polygons on a WPF canvas, but wouldn't want the hassle (189 segments all of which have rounded edges...).
Same goes for rebuilding the graphic in SVG, continuing the "web" approach.

Forgoing the graphic and using an abstraction (e.g. a table) is a last resort solution.

Comment: How large are the images?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480351/how-can-i-draw-polygons-on-an-html5-canvas-through-a-javascript-function

Comment: @RobertHarvey You mean the resolution? I'm using it at 1200*1000px at the moment. Since it's a scanned image, I can basically use any resolution

Comment: @level_zebra Thanks for the link! The problem isnt't the drawing on the canvas, though, but rather what to draw. The shape that must be drawn is different for every segment and every state of that segment. So how do I get the shape needed for the segment I clicked on?